# Remove Text import prompt

Tags: javascript, excel

Recently I was working on export to excel by using below link. This function is simple and works fine. But after I download the file and open it, instead of opening directly excel sheet , it opens text import prompt. Once I click okay button it opens excel sheet. How do I make it to open directly.

```
[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/hybrid13i/JXrwM/
```

Comment: to open without import you shoud produce `xls` or `xlsx` format

Comment: I tried but it dint work...

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to import data from a text file by using Microsoft Excel: You can open the text file in Excel, or you can import the text file as an external data range. To export data from Excel to a text file, use the Save As command.

There are two commonly used text file formats:

- Delimited text files (.txt), in which the TAB character (ASCII
  character code 009) typically separates each field of text.
- Comma separated values text files (.csv), in which the comma
  character (,) typically separates each field of text.

You can change the separator character that is used in both delimited and .csv text files. This may be necessary to make sure that the import or export operation works the way that you want it to.

Source:-
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-5250ac4c-663c-47ce-937b-339e391393ba

Comment: I don't want to make any import options. When i download file it should directly open excel file

Comment: I understand, you have problem that, it do not open directly in Excel, Then you can follow this procedure in the link 
http://www.solveyourtech.com/how-to-open-csv-files-with-excel-by-default/

Comment: Thanks but it reflects only in my system because i make its settings in my computer. I wanted through coding.

Comment: For now, this is merely impossible as CSV file is not intelligent to keep such type of settings in it, can't say in future. Also, the file manager should recognise the extension of the file, if Excel applications are present to open CSV file.

Comment: @user3335796 It is not possible at CSV level as suggested by Shaggy, you have to make a change in your application settings itself. By default all office programs are tweaked to open excel,ppt, doc files directly.Opening other structured documents like xml, csv require some settings before importing.